# Multiple parameters to named route rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, named-routing

I have the following route:

```
match "sports/:sport(/:view)" => 'sports#show', as:'sport_path'
```

How do I call `sport_path(sport, view)`?  When I try:

```
sport_path(params[:sport], 1)
```

The resulting url is: `/sports/5.1`.  It should be `/sports/5/1` (notice the dot instead of the slash)

Comment: Did you try: `sport_path(params[:sport], :view => 1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had another route named `sport`.  *face-palm*